# How to escape double quotes between JS and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to construct a String in JS that can be passed into JSON as an with a very particular format. Desired result is a string of the following form:

> ["PNG","350x150","127 KB"]

Where `PNG` correspond to a particular image's type, where `350x150` is the image's dimensions and where `127 KB` is the image's size. Each of these threee values are string variables:

```
var imgType = getImageType(); // Returns "PNG"
var imgDim = getImageDim(); // Returns "350x150"
var imgSize = getImageSize(); // Returns "127 KB"

var imgDescription = '["' + imgType + '","' + imgDim + '","' + imgSize + '"]';

// Sanity check
alert(imgDescription);

iVO.images[thisImage] = {
    "fizz":"buzz",
    "imgDesc":imgDescription,
    "foo":"bar"
}

alert(JSON.stringify(iVO));
```

The first alert (on the `imgDescription` variable) prints:

> ["PNG","350x150","127 KB"]

So far, so good. However, the minute we pass it to the `iVO` construct and stringify the resultant JSON, it generates the following output (after I pretty print format it):

```
{
    "images":
    {
        "4490i45"":
        {
            "fizz":"buzz",
            "imgDesc":"[\"PNG\",\"350x150\",\"127 KB\"]",
            "foo":"bar"
        }
    }
}
```

All of my double quotes (") have been escaped (\")!!! Also, the value for `imgDesc` is enclosed in double-quotes, which is not what we want (see desired JSON below):

When I send this JSON back to the server its causing the server to choke.

Not sure what is going on here but I've tried several other suggestions, including replacing my double-quotes with `'\x22'` instances which didn't help.

Any ideas as to what would fix this to get the desired result from `JSON.stringify(iVO)`? Ultimately that's the only thing that matters, that the we end up sending the following to the server:

```
{
    "images":
    {
        "4490i45"":
        {
            "fizz":"buzz",
            "imgDesc":["PNG","350x150","127 KB"],
            "foo":"bar"
        }
    }
}
```

No escaped double-quotes, and the value for `imgDesc` is not double-quoted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding extra escaped quotes?

Comment: Sounds like a decent suggestion @dweiss - any chance you can provide a code example? Thanks again!

Comment: Your target is not valid JSON ("imgDesc":["PNG","350x150","127 KB"] etc.).

Comment: For example, if you tried 
var imgDescription = '["\"' + imgType + '\"","\"' + imgDim + '\"","\"' + imgSize + '\""]';

Comment: Oh, I thought you were TRYING to force quotes.  Now I see that you're just trying to get the JSON to parse properly.  Anurag's answer probably will suffice, in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just put imgDescription as regular array

```
var imgDescription = [imgType , imgDim, imgSize];
```

Stringify should take care of what you are trying to do, otherwise you are passing imgDescription as a string and stringify would escape the quotes.

e.g.

```
var imgType = "PNG";
var imgDim = "350x150";
var imgSize = "127 KB";
var d = {
    "fizz":"buzz",
    "imgDesc":[imgType , imgDim, imgSize],
    "foo":"bar"
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
```

Output:

```
{"fizz":"buzz","imgDesc":["PNG","350x150","127 KB"],"foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: +1 Just about to add the same answer ;). You're stringifying a string, so of course it's escaping it. If you stringify an *object* you'll get perfectly formatted JSON.

Comment: The point is that JSON.stringify actually returns an assumed SINGLE quoted string. the string is actually '{"fizz":"buzz",...' and as soon  as you put that string in a double encoded string, there are problems.